# Swift addTarget to a button and call function in different View Controller file from UIview file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, addtarget

now I practice applying the MVC pattern in my Swift project.
I have one View Controller (VC) file and one UIView file.

In the VC file, I added the UIView file like below.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var myView = MyView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(myView)
        myView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.bounds.size)
        // and other codes...
    }

    @objc func showDeleteAlert() {
        print("showDelete is pressed")
    }
}
```

Then, inside the UIView file, I added some views and buttons (I just copy the button part).

```
class MyView: UIView {
    lazy var deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("delete", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(target: MyViewController, action: #selector(showDeleteAlert), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside) // -> I get error in here saying "Cannot find 'showDeleteAlert' in scope"

        return button
    }()

// and more codes...
}
```

What I want to do here is how to set the target to showDeleteAlert function when the deleteButton is pressed?

I saw tutorials add "self" as a target argument, but in my case, I separated view and controller so not really sure how to access the function in MyViewController.

Thank you...

Comment: An easy workaround is to use the notification.

Comment: It should be something in the nature of the following.  button.addTarget(self.MyViewController, action: #selector(self.MyViewController.showDeleteAlert), for: .touchUpInside)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. move `addTarget` into view controller `viewDidLoad`:

```
myView.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDeleteAlert), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

2. If you wanna make button private(which is a good practice), you can add proxy func to your `MyView`

```
func addDeleteButtonTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector) {
    deleteButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And call it:

```
myView.addDeleteButtonTarget(self, action: #selector(showDeleteAlert))
```

In any case, you cant call `button.addTarget(target: MyViewController, ...)`, because you need to pass an instance of the `MyViewController`, not just a class name.